# IONIC3: disable WAL mode in android PIE

Tags: sqlite, ionic3

IONIC3: Hello how can I disable WAL mode in adroid PIE, I'm using ionic3 and I cannot find a clear answer yet. I have a database that copied my assets to the root of the application using: **window.plugins.sqlDB.copyDbFromStorage(this.nameBD, 0, this.ubicacionBD+this.nameBD, deleteolddb,succesfunc, errorfunc)**

Please Help